# Suitable basis functions for approximation

Tags: approximation, regression, approximation-theory, approximate-integration

Given :

function $g : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, $d$ dimensional Gaussian random variable $Y$ with density $f(Y)$

A function $L : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ :

$$L(x) = \int g(x*Y)f(Y)dY$$

Here $*$ denotes multiplication element by element : $[x_1,x_2,...,x_d]*[y_1,y_2,...,y_d] = [x_1y_1,x_2y_2,...,x_dy_d]$

Function $L$ is very difficult to evaluate. To evaluate $L$ at given $x$ I will approximate it numerically by sampling $y_1,...y_n$ from density of $f(Y)$ and then take average of $g(x*y_i)$. So I want to have some approximation of $L$ in terms of functions that are easier to compute.

My plan:

1) Calculate $L(x_1),L(x_2),...L(x_i)$ for some vectors $x_i$

2) Chose basis functions that are easy to calculate $\psi_1,\psi_2,...,\psi_m$

3) Make regression of $L(x_1),L(x_2),...L(x_i)$ on $\psi$ to obtain representation of $L(x) = \sum_{i=1}^ma_i\psi_i(x)$

**My question is how to chose basis functions $\psi$?**

I would be happy if you pointed me to some articles or anything where similar questions were investigated

What I have found so far is related to Laplace approximation of integrals. Since $Y$ is Gaussian its density is exponential and if I understood correctly Laplace method, there should be some $y_0$ such that $\psi(x) = g(x*y_0)f(y_0)$ would be good choice of basis function. Right now I am testing this idea

Comment: The function $g$ could be approximated by Hermite polynomials, at least if $d$ is not too large. The integration task for L could then be done analytically for every $x$, I assume. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for oyur reply! Are you sure that we can integrate analytically Gaussian density?

Comment: Polynomials: yes. If the components of your Y are additionally independent, these are just sums of moments. If not Isserlis' theorem might help (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem).  Hermite polynomials are especially suited to approximate functions of Gaussian random variables. Your function does not exactly in this framework, but I would say, it is still promising :-).